# Is it possible to archive or delte old draft/unsent mailings?

Tags: mailing

We've been using an online version of civi (5.39.1 on a Drupal install) which has been great but after nearly a year we have almost 160 draft mailings that were never sent. I think the users who were new created quite a lot of them when just getting used to the system. In any case I'd like to be able to simply delete a whole bunch of these or archive them as the list of drafts is becoming a bit much. I can't add an extension as it's an online service with limited scope for extensions. Is there a way that i can do this?

Comment: You can definitely delete them. When looking at the list of drafts at the far right you should see a "more" dropdown and delete is in there. Unless maybe with this online service your permissions to delete are restricted.

Comment: Hi. Yes, it turns out it was a permission thing. My permissions have now been adjusted and I can now delete them one by one which is better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the  [Delete Draft/Unscheduled Mailings periodically extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/delete-draftunscheduled-mailings-periodically) and set the number of days the draft mailing should be deleted in the Delete Unscheduled Mailings scheduled job. The provider should be OK with adding this extension in.

You can manually delete with the permission `CiviMail: delete in CiviMail` .  I'm wondering on your access level, you should see if it is not full CiviCRM Admin / have this permission?
[image]

I don't know what online service you are using but it needs to be updated to the latest [security release](https://civicrm.org/security/releases) as well.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have raised this with them as it makes a lot of sense and so I'll await feedback but in the meantime, they have adjusted my permissions so that I can delete them one by one. It's progress. :)